# How to make a loader showing the number of uploaded lines with JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I've tried a lot of things before, but I can't seem to process how to do it correctly.

Here's my problem : I want my users to upload an Excel File and then fetch the lines to upload it on my database. I've made the JavaScript and PHP scripts and it works pretty well, but while it's fetching the lines, I want to show the user a loader saying "Line current_line of total_lines". I've tried the following script :

But it does not seem to work and I don't understand why. In my PHP, "finances/import" upload the lines with a for loop and iterate a session variable then read in "finances/import_progress" but the loader is updated when the import is over and I don't understand why.

I've tried to change the fetch in CheckImportProgress with XHR and the onprogress method but it didn't change anything.

```js
fetch(baseurl + 'finances/import', {
    method: 'POST',
    ContentType: 'multipart/form-data; boundary=—-WebKitFormBoundaryfgtsKTYLsT7PNUVD',
    body: form
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    if (json.success) {
      //On récupère le nombre de lignes du fichier Excel uploadé
      nbrlignes = json.nbrlines
      document.querySelector('.infoslignes').style.display = 'block'
      document.querySelector('.ligneimport').innerHTML = 0
      document.querySelector('.lignetotal').innerHTML = nbrlignes
      fetch(baseurl + 'finances/import_excel', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          page: document.querySelector('input[name="page"]').value,
          file: json.file
        })
      })
      setInterval(checkImportProgress, 500, nbrlignes)
    } else {
      document.querySelector('.error-import').style.display = 'block'
      document.querySelector('.error-import').innerHTML = json.message
      document.querySelector('.import-text').style.display = 'block'
      document.querySelector('.import-progress').style.display = 'none'
    }
  })

function checkImportProgress(nbrlignes) {
  fetch(baseurl + 'finances/import_progress/' + nbrlignes)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      document.querySelector('.import-progress-bar').style.width = ((json.row / nbrlignes) * 100) + '%'
      document.querySelector('.import-progress-bar').innerHTML = Math.round(((json.row / nbrlignes) * 100)) + '%'
      document.querySelector('.ligneimport').innerHTML = json.row
      if (nbrlignes === json.row)
        clearInterval()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fundamental issue is the idea of retrieving the amount of lines from the backend *whilst uploading it*. The backend cannot access this data until the upload is complete.

You'll want to use a package such as [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#columns) to make it *much* easier for you to retrieve the line count on the *frontend*:

```
const getExcelFileRowCount = async file => {
    const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    const worksheet = await workbook.xlsx.read(file.stream());
    
    // Doesn't technically need to be column 1, but that will always exist, so it's fine.
    const rows = worksheet.getColumn(1);
    return rows["_worksheet"]["_rows"].length;
};
```

Secondly, it would be very difficult to know which line is currently being processed, since technically the upload isn't processing individual lines, but the *bytes* themselves.

So, to give the user a *faux* approximation of what "line" is currently being processed, you can use the `uploadProgress` value from a library such as [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro):

```
const rowCount = await getExcelFileRowCount(fileInput);

const handleProgressUpdate = progress => {
    console.log(Math.floor(rowCount * progress));
};

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", fileInput);

axios.post("finances/import", formData, {
    onUploadProgress: handleProgressUpdate
});
```

Hope this helps mate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So basically you're telling me to process the lines on client side instead of server side ? I think it could be a good solution if I understand it correctly, I will try this, thanks again !

Comment: @QuentinSchifferle Exactly. If you need to access information *before* it hits server-side, your only option is to ever get that information client-side first.

Comment: @QuentinSchifferle If you found this answer helpful, please upvote. It helps others who may have this same issue in the future see this answer :)

Comment: Thanks mate.  I accepted your answer, it seems to be best way to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

How about, try to read the file in js, then store it in variable. After that, you can use a batch request for uploading your data. In that way, you can display to the user what data is currently uploading.